# Using Pro to apply specific USN

Tags: apt, patch, ubuntu-pro

I’m looking at Ubunto Pro for a future work project.  During testing I noticed that when I install a patch via USN it automatically applied the latest update for that package.

For example:
I wanted to apply USN-6270-1 which would upgrade xxd from 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13 to 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm3.  But xxd got upgraded to 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm4 which is part of USN-6302-1 and the latest xxd patch.

Is there a way to force pro to upgrade to the version I want (+esm3) and not automatically go to the latest (+esm4)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release is this for?

Answer (score 1):

Apt will try to install the highest-version package available from any source that it is aware of. That's why you must be careful about managing your sources.

It's not about "forcing Pro". It's about using apt.

To specify a version:

```
sudo apt install package_name=version
```

Example:

```
sudo apt install xxd=2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm3
```

It's the same command if the package is already installed.

**NOTE**: The next time `unattended upgrades` runs, or you run a manual `sudo apt upgrade`, the version will again upgrade to `+esm4`. To remain on a lower version (which most users should NOT usually do), you must use apt-marking or apt-pinning.

Comment: Note also that **version +esm3 may not be available anymore in the repositories**, which is why you may not be able to install it this way.